# Can CUDA Toolkit 7.5 be used on Visual Studio 2015 with VS 2013 Platform Toolkit

Tags: visual-studio, opencv, visual-studio-2013, cuda, visual-studio-2015

I want to install CUDA for OpenCV, but the current toolkit (7.5) isn't compatible with Visual Studio 2015. My questions are -

- Will installing VS 2013 Express allow me to use its toolkit on 2015 to build OpenCV with CUDA?
- If I build the OpenCV CUDA on Visual Studio 2013, can I use the OpenCV CUDA libraries on Visual Studio 2015?

Thanks for helping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know if this will work for OpenCV, but I just found out that it works for CUDA, so it might as well.

To allow CUDA projects to load in VS2015, you have to copy the extension files from the VS2013 folder to the VS2015 extension folder. For me they were located at:

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\BuildCustomizations

C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\BuildCustomizations

Copy the CUDA 7.5.targets, .props and .xml files. You can now load and compile CUDA projects in VS2015.

Source, [my blogpost](http://robbinmarcus.blogspot.nl/2016/02/cuda-in-visual-studio-2015.html).

I have the VS2015 and VS2013 community editions installed.

Comment: Yes. But as mentioned on my blog: CUDA 8.0RC is released and supports VS 2015 natively. Do note that at time of writing only up to VS2015 update 1 is supported, so if you run VS2015 update 2, you can't compile those projects. You can load and run VS2013 projects just fine in VS2015 with this, no need to use this hacky solution anymore.